# jquery slider rotation function

Tags: jquery, slider, rotation

I'm using a small plug-slider that has 2 main functions **rotate()** and **rotateSwitch()**

```
rotate = function(){    
    var triggerID = $active.attr("rel") - 1;
    var image_reelPosition = triggerID * imageWidth;

    $(".paging a").removeClass('active');
    $active.addClass('active');

    //Slider Animation
    $(".image_reel").animate({ 
        left: -image_reelPosition
    }, 500 );

}; 


rotateSwitch = function(){      
    play = setInterval(function(){
        $active = $('.paging a.active').next();
        if ( $active.length === 0) {
            $active = $('.paging a:first'); //go back to first
        }
        rotate(); //Trigger the paging and slider function
    }, 7000);  (7 seconds)
};

rotateSwitch();
```

This works well if the paging buttons are as follows:

```
<div class="paging">
  <a href="#" rel="1">1</a>
  <a href="#" rel="2">2</a>
  <a href="#" rel="3">3</a>
  <a href="#" rel="4">4</a>
</div>
```

But my problem (for needs of style) is that the pagination is made in this way;

```
<div class="paging">
      <ul>
                <li><a href="#" rel="1">1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" rel="2">2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" rel="3">3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" rel="4">4</a></li>
            </ul>
</div>
```

Then the rotation is not working. I think the problem is not finding the link below because this line: (in the rotateSwitch() function )

```
$active = $('.paging a.active').next();
    if ( $active.length === 0) {
        $active = $('.paging a:first'); //go back to first
    }
```

If this is the error, how to find the next() child  of the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `a.active` doesn't have siblings inside the `li`, hence no result from `.next()`. You'll need to traverse through the parent to locate the next `li` first and then dive back down to the link within:

```
$active = $('.paging a.active').parent().next().find('a');
```